# Running ./runInsaller for Oracle 11g installation in Linux 6 gives could not execute auto check for display colors using command

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, redhat

I have installed virtual box.On that I installed Redhat Linux 6 and now I am trying to install Oracle 11g on the Linux. But as I run the `./runInstaller` for that I get the below error:

> could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo.Check if DISPLAY variable is set. <<<< FAILED

I already set the display variable but it gives could not open the display for machine-name when I `echo $DISPLAY`.

Can someone suggest how to run installer in console only (without gui)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use so-called "Silent mode". The key for that is `-silent`. This mode can run without X display, but it's also unable to ask you questions (Oracle being Oracle), so you will also have to prepare response file containing all answers in advance. The key is `-responsefile <file>`.

See also:

- http://pingtool.org/oracle-11-install-without-x/
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/app_nonint.htm#LADBI414

Or, since you're dealing with a virtual machine, it might be simpler to install a lightweight desktop environment like LXDE or XFCE, install what you need, and then remove the DE once you're done.

Comment: I used the silent mode installation through the response file.It worked.Thank you for your valuable suggestion.